# Meaning of partial derivatives of a vibrating string

Tags: calculus, derivatives

**Problem:** Let $y(x, t)$ denote the vertical displacement of a vibrating string at a point $x$ on the string at time $t$. Suppose the string is stretched out along the $x$-axis, and the vibrations are up and down like a guitar string. What is the physical meaning of the functions $y_t(x,t)$ and $y_x(x,t)$?

**My solution:** $y_t(x,t)$ represents the frequency of the vibrating string; $y_x(x,t)$ is the amplitude of the vibrations.

Would this be correct? If not then please give me a hint.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unit check: $y_t(x,t)$ has units [length]/[time]. This is the unit of velocity, not frequency which is 1/[s]. $y_x(x,t)$ has units [length]/[length], which is unitless.

$y_t(x,t)$ is precisely the vertical velocity of a particle located at $x$ at time $t$. On the other hand $y_x(x,t)$ represents the slope of the string at location $x$, time $t$.